# How to assign a dynamic value in the <align>?

Tags: layout, xml

Need to align the title of the column(header_css_class) and content(align) dynamically of return of a method.

I tried like this in **after** calling a methodo and failed.

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <sales_order_grid_update_handle>
        <reference name="sales_order.grid">
            <action method="addColumnAfter" ifconfig="dexxtz_customgrid/general/active">
                <columnId>payment_method</columnId>
                <arguments>
                    <header>Payment Method</header>
                    <index>payment_method</index>
                    <header_css_class>a-center</header_css_class>-->
                    <align>center</align>
                    <filter_index>payment.method</filter_index>
                    <type>text</type>
                    <width>100px</width>
                </arguments>
                <after helper="customgrid/getAfter" />
            </action>
        </reference>
    </sales_order_grid_update_handle>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
        <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_index>
        <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

Modified the **arguments** calling a function from my helper.

Example layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <sales_order_grid_update_handle translate="label" module="dexxtz_customgrid">
        <reference name="sales_order.grid">
            <action method="addColumnAfter" ifconfig="dexxtz_customgrid/general/active">
                <columnId>payment_method</columnId>
                <arguments helper="customgrid/getPaymentColumnParams" />
                <after helper="customgrid/getAfter" />
            </action>
        </reference>
    </sales_order_grid_update_handle>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
        <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_grid>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_index>
        <update handle="sales_order_grid_update_handle" />
    </adminhtml_sales_order_index>
</layout>
```

Example helper:

```
class Dexxtz_Customgrid_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function getPaymentColumnParams(){
        return array('header' => 'Payment Method',
                     'index' => 'payment_method',
                     'filter_index' => 'payment.method',
                     'header_css_class' => 'a-center',
                     'align' => 'center',
                     'type' => 'text',
                     'width' => '100px');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mark this as accepted.

Comment: I need wait more 1 day @Marius